# Artifact in image translation by Fourier phase shift in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, fft

The following code is creating an artefact when shifting images by Fourier phase shift:

The code of the phase shift itself is:

```py
def phase_shift(fimage, dx, dy):
    # Shift the phase of the fourier transform of an image
    dims = fimage.shape
    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-dims[1] / 2, dims[1] / 2), np.arange(-dims[0] / 2, dims[0] / 2))

    kx = -1j * 2 * np.pi * x / dims[1]
    ky = -1j * 2 * np.pi * y / dims[0]

    shifted_fimage = fimage * np.exp(-(kx * dx + ky * dy))

    return shifted_fimage
```

Usage to actually shift the image and get the shifted image:

```py
def translate_by_phase_shift(image, dx, dy):
    # Get the fourier transform
    fimage = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftn(image))
    # Phase shift
    shifted_fimage = phase_shift(fimage, dx, dy)
    # Inverse transform -> translated image
    shifted_image = np.real(np.fft.ifftn(np.fft.ifftshift(shifted_fimage)))

    return shifted_image
```

The artifact is shown in the images below (image has even dimensions). Top row is context (entire image), bottom is the close-up in the red rectangle. Left: reference image. Middle: shifted with the above code and subject to artifact. Right: what it looks when using `cv2.warpAffine()` using the same shifts.

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong in the code above that creates this artifact?

[UPDATE] One of the comment suggested to use `scipy.ndimage.fourier.fourier_shift()`. So I did just that:

```
fourier_shifted_image = fourier_shift(np.fft.fftn(image), shift)
shifted_image = np.fft.ifftn(fourier_shifted_image)
```

and plotted the real part (`shifted_image.real`)

In fact, it also produces the exact same artifact (see image below, right-hand side), which I guess rule out a mistake in my custom code `phase_shift()` above?

[image]

[UPDATE] Now that we ruled out my phase_shift() function, here's a reproducible code, provided that you download the image array from here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dmbv56xfqkv8qqz/image.npy?dl=0

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.fourier import fourier_shift


# Load the image (update path according to your case)
image = np.load(os.path.expanduser('~/DDS/46P_Wirtanen/image.npy'))
# Shift vector
shift = np.array([-3.75, -7.5 ])
# Phase-shift
fourier_shifted_image = fourier_shift(np.fft.fftn(image), shift)
shifted_image = np.fft.ifftn(fourier_shifted_image)

interp_method = 'hanning'
zoomfov = [1525, 1750, 1010, 1225]
vmin = np.percentile(image, 0.1)
vmax = np.percentile(image, 99.8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(14, 6), sharex=True,sharey=True)
ax[0].imshow(image, origin='lower', cmap='gray', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, interpolation=interp_method)
ax[0].set_title('Original image')
ax[1].imshow(shifted_image.real, origin='lower', cmap='gray', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, interpolation=interp_method)
ax[1].set_title('with scipy.ndimage.fourier.fourier_shift()')
plt.axis(zoomfov)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And the output looks like this:
[image]

[UPDATE]
Following the reply from Cris, I played with other interpolation methods from opencv with a logarithmic scaling of the intensity, I arrive to similar conclusions: the artifact is indeed also present with the Lanczos flag in `cv2.warpAffine()` - although very faint - and the cubic one clearly works better for this case of undersampled objects (here, stars):

[image]

The code to get to this:

```py
# Compare interpolation methods
import cv2
# Fourier phase shift.
fourier_shifted = fourier_shift(np.fft.fftn(image), shift)
fourier_shifted_image = np.fft.ifftn(fourier_shifted).real
# Use opencv
Mtrans = np.float32([[1,0,shift[1]],[0,1, shift[0]]])
shifted_image_cubic = cv2.warpAffine(image, Mtrans, image.shape[::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
shifted_image_lanczos  = cv2.warpAffine(image, Mtrans, image.shape[::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)

zoomfov = [1525, 1750, 1010, 1225]
pmin = 2
pmax = 99.999

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(19, 7), sharex=True,sharey=True)
ax[0].imshow(fourier_shifted_image, origin='lower', cmap='gray',
             vmin=np.percentile(fourier_shifted_image, pmin), vmax=np.percentile(fourier_shifted_image, pmax),
             interpolation=interp_method, norm=LogNorm())
add_rectangle(zoomfov, ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('shifted with Fourier phase shift')
ax[1].imshow(shifted_image_cubic, origin='lower', cmap='gray',
             vmin=np.percentile(shifted_image_cubic, pmin), vmax=np.percentile(shifted_image_cubic, pmax),
             interpolation=interp_method, norm=LogNorm())
add_rectangle(zoomfov, ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('with cv2.warpAffine(...,flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)')
ax[2].imshow(shifted_image_lanczos, origin='lower', cmap='gray',
             vmin=np.percentile(shifted_image_lanczos, pmin), vmax=np.percentile(shifted_image_lanczos, pmax),
             interpolation=interp_method, norm=LogNorm())
#ax[2].imshow(shifted_image.real, origin='lower', cmap='gray', vmin=np.percentile(Llights_prep[frame], pmin), vmax=np.percentile(Llights_prep[frame], pmax), interpolation=interp_method)
add_rectangle(zoomfov, ax[2])
ax[2].set_title('with cv2.warpAffine(...,flags=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4) ')
plt.axis(zoomfov)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.1, hspace=None)
plt.show()
```

And to reply to Cris' questions, indeed undersampled stars is of course inescapable with our modest amateur imaging systems (a poor 130 mm diameter), and I naively applied the same algorithm than what I use for professional, bigger instruments where this problem did not show.

Comment: I don't understand your questions. Code to "use" an image? And FT phase shift is a basic way to translate an image instead of doing interpolation, which is what warpAffine() (from opencv) does.

Comment: Just a completely unsophisticated guess: Are you using a precise enough data type?

Comment: Original image converted to float32 before processing... I can try float64 but i'd expect scipy would do that internally if that could be an issue?

Comment: Please share your code for display, I think your problem is there.

Comment: To understand an Fourier artefact, it can be useful to remember that the operation is linear. Here you have the exact outcome as well. Subtract the two, and run an IFFT on _just_ the artefact.

Comment: @CrisLuengo this is unrelated to display. Ripples are in the numpy array itself, and as you can see, does not show up in the original image that uses the same code for display. For completeness, i've added a simpler reproducible code

Comment: @Wall-E: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is related to the way that the image is displayed, and to undersampling of the image. The code is correct, but inappropriate for the image.

#### 1. Undersampling

The image has some very sharp transitions. Some stars show only in one single pixel. This is the hallmark of undersampling. In a properly sampled image, a single point of light (no matter how small) appears as an Airy disk (in the case of an ideal lens) in the image, and should occupy several pixels to prevent aliasing.

I'm assuming that the imaging cannot be changed, and is optimized for the application.

However, it is important to note how the image is sampled to be able to chose appropriate image processing tools.

In this case, the undersampled transitions mean that Fourier-based interpolation is not ideal.

#### 2. Fourier-based interpolation

When shifting or scaling the image through the Fourier domain, a sinc interpolator is used. This is the ideal interpolator, and corresponds to a rectangular window in the Fourier domain. The sinc interpolator extends infinitely (or at least to the edges of the image), and decays with 1/x, which is quite slow. It is therefore not ideal in the case of undersampled images.

Because the undersampled image has sharp transitions, the sinc interpolator causes ringing (as do many other interpolators). And because of the slow decay of the sinc function, this ringing carries very far.

For example, the artificial sharp transition in this figure (blue), when interpolated through the Fourier domain (red), shows strong ringing that carries very far. This figure contrasts that with other interpolators that carry the ringing to different distances.

[image: Plot showing the interpolation of a sharp transition, using various interpolators]

#### 3. Image display

The image is displayed in the question by stretching the contrast very strongly. This is meant to allow observation of dim stars, but also strongly enhances the ringing caused the sharp transitions at those stars. In the plot above, imagine stretching and clipping the y-axis so you only see the region `y=[0,0.01]`. The ringing will look like a black-and-white pattern.

#### 4. Alternative interpolators

The plot above shows the effect of different interpolators on a sharp transition. When applied to shift the image in the question, this is the result:

[image: Region from OP's image, shifted using different interpolators]

For the three methods on the bottom row, the ringing is not observable because it happens in a region that is fully saturated in the image display. Using a different range of grey-values in the display might show some ringing here too.

All these interpolators are designed to approximate the ideal sinc interpolator, but with a shorter spatial footprint so that they are cheaper to compute. Therefore, they all show some ringing at undersampled transitions.

The only interpolators that do not cause ringing at sharp edges are linear interpolation and nearest neighbor interpolation. Whether these are suitable for your application depends on the application, I cannot say.

---

This is the code I used to make the graph above:

```
a = double((0:99)<50);
b = resample(a,20,0,'ft');
c = resample(a,20,0,'3-cubic');
d = resample(a,20,0,'lanczos8');
a = resample(a,20,0,'nn');
plot(a)
hold on
plot(b)
plot(c)
plot(d)
legend({'input','sinc','cubic','Lanczos (8)'})
set(gca,'xlim',[600,1400],'ylim',[-0.2,1.2])
set(gca,'fontsize',16)
set(gca,'linewidth',1)
set(get(gca,'children'),'linewidth',2)
set(gca,'Position',[0.07,0.11,0.9,0.815])
```

The function `resample` is in [DIPimage](http://www.diplib.org/), you could use `imresize` instead, except for the `'ft'` method, which simply pads the frequency domain with zeros, leading to a sinc interpolation.

Comment: Cris, that is very interesting. The opencv warpAffine() interpolation was not causing the ringing using the same intensity scaling values and same display interpolators. So are we in the case that I'd rather use a non-Fourier based method to avoid this completely? Or can't I use some kind of windowing? I tried padding the image before Fourier phase-shifting but it didn't help.

Comment: The interpolator in opencv warpAffine() was using the lanczos one, it showed no ringing at the same intensity scaling:
```cv2.warpAffine(image, translation_matrix, image.shape[::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)```. I'll try the other ones and see where's the sweet spot regarding the different interpolators as the linear one really blur things out too much.

Comment: Cris, any chance you'd embed the code for your test? I'm unclear on how you got the fourier interpolation done on that step pattern but would love to make a similar one for 1D artificially generated undersampled star patterns.

Comment: @Wall-E: Windowing won’t help. I would suggest you use a spatial interpolation. But if your image is undersampled, really the best you can do is stick to integer shifts. I can share the code tonight, when I’m behind my computer again. But I used MATLAB for the plot. What I did was generate a short 1D signal with values 1 and 0, then interpolate it 20x using different interpolators. This shows their characteristic. When shifting instead of zooming, you’d sample those output signals at locations away from the knots.

Comment: No pb, feel free to share the matlab code, i'm equally fine with that, whenever you have time.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ndimage.fourier_shift, as far as I know that does not create any artefacts.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Interestingly, it produces the exact same artefact! See update in my post.